# Fetching audio file via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, streaming

I need to fetch an audio file using Ajax and receive it in the form an array of bytes. My backend is on PHP.

Currently I am using

```
<?php 
echo  file_get_contents("./mainFile.mp3");
?>
```

This lets me return the audio file in the form an array of bytes. But how can I receive it in Javascript as a byte array.  I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray) on SO

But this does not seem to be the proper way. Can anyone please suggest something ???

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "array of bytes". What for? What does the JavaScript do with the data?

Comment: Not sure of what you are trying to do here. Doesn't any reader will load and stream an audio file? Why loading it raw into PHP?

Comment: Actually I wish to play the audio file using actionscript using the appendBytes function . I wish to feed this byte array fetched by AJAX  to my actionscript class. 

P.S: I know the same thing can be done by directly fetching the audio by actionscript  .. but the design of my site forces me to use JS for this purpose

Comment: does the link I posted not work for you? I glanced over their code... seems like it would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `overrideMimeType()` to `"text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"` like so:

```
$.ajax( {

        url: "php.php",

        beforeSend: function( xhr ){
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
        },

        success: function( text ) {
        var i, l = text.length, bytes = [];

            for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
            bytes.push( text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF );
            }
        console.log( bytes.length );
        }

});
```

Note that this is extremely futile, bit operations in javascript are extremely fast on strings+charCodeAt only. Even faster than on typed arrays, as I shockingly discovered in an application of mine.

The text/plain isn't important, but the charset is.

Answer (score 1):

Save a file named: raw_audio.php

```
<?php 
    echo  file_get_contents("./mainFile.mp3");
?>
```

Now load that php file from your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
url:'raw_audio.php',
success: function(data)
{
 var raw=data;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'arraybuffer' response type:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking to do is to read the file via ajax in a "binary" way.  I just googled binary ajax and this is the first result that came up... not sure if it's useful...
http://nagoon97.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/reading-binary-files-using-ajax/