# encode base 64 in javascript, decode unicode in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode, encoding, base64

I'm writing a client-side code in JS , which should be compatible with a third-party c# service which I cannot modify at all.

The service supplies a base64 **unicode** encoded string (a JSON), 
for the sake of the (simplified) example this is the c# code:

```
var myString = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("{\"counter\":0}");
var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(myString);
```

which results in : "ewAiAGMAbwB1AG4AdABlAHIAIgA6ADAAfQA="

now I need to update this encoded JSON at the client-side, and return a valid base64 string which will be decoded by this C# code:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
string decodedString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
```

All the solutions/examples I've found online resulted in the decoding functions to output a invalid result.
for example, when using the basic `window.btoa("{\"counter\":1}")` resulted in `eyJjb3VudGVyIjoxfQ==`
which in turn , when decoding on the c# app, will be cause a format exception at best, or result in total gibberish.

any Ideas?

Comment: When using `window.btoa` it uses UTF8 encoding, when you try to decode it as a Unicode string, it will ofcourse end up as gibberish. The C# conversion code is fun, but if you don't supply it Unicode input, it will ofcourse crash when doing `Encoding.Unicode.GetString`. What happens when you change `Unicode` to `UTF8` in the C# code?

Comment: For clarity, Unicode under Windows (and C#) means UTF16-LE. You'll have to figure out how to get a string encoded as UTF-16 in javascript.

Comment: Well if I change it to `Encoding.UTF8` then the decoding works fine.
But if I change it to `Encoding.UTF16` it crashed. The problem is I have no control over the C# code, I need to figure it out on the JS side –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @roeland mentioned the "trick" is to encode the string to UTF16-LE first, and then encode the UTF16-LE string to base64.

The way I've solved it is by first converting the string to a Byte Array using:

```
function str2ByteArr(str) {
    var bytes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
        bytes.push(0);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

the result for  `"{\"counter\":0}"`   will be :

```
[123, 0, 34, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 48, 0, 125, 0]
```

and then converting the array to base64:

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}
```

and to sum it all up :

```
var byteArr = str2ByteArr(str);
return arrayBufferToBase64(byteArr);
```

the result is :

```
"ewAiAGMAbwB1AG4AdABlAHIAIgA6ADAAfQA="
```

another way I've found to convert string to byte Arrays for 'utf-8','utf-16be' and 'utf-16le' encoding is by using [Text.Encoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder) where you can choose the encoding explicitly like so:

```
var textEncoder = new TextEncoder('utf-16le')
textEncoder.encode("{\"counter\":0}")
```

but this is not supported by explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer assumes that the high byte is always 0.  This is not always the case and in fact encoding *私はGoogle翻訳を使用しました* does not work.  The trick is to use the technique found here: [How to convert a String to Bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray) when converting the string to a UTF16 Little Endian array:

```
bytes.push(charCode & 0xFF);  // low byte
bytes.push((charCode & 0xFF00) >>> 8); // high byte
```

Full solution:

```
function base64Encode(str)
{
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
    {
        var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(charCode & 0xFF);
        bytes.push((charCode & 0xFF00) >>> 8);
    }

    var len = bytes.length;
    var buffer = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        buffer += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }

    return window.btoa(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the Java Script Code for decode :

```
var Base64 = { _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=", encode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i, s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = Base64._utf8_encode(e); while (f < e.length) { n = e.charCodeAt(f++); r = e.charCodeAt(f++); i = e.charCodeAt(f++); s = n >> 2; o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4; u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6; a = i & 63; if (isNaN(r)) { u = a = 64 } else if (isNaN(i)) { a = 64 } t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a) } return t }, decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n, r, i; var s, o, u, a; var f = 0; e = e.replace(/++[++^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, ""); while (f < e.length) { s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++)); n = s << 2 | o >> 4; r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2; i = (u & 3) << 6 | a; t = t + String.fromCharCode(n); if (u != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(r) } if (a != 64) { t = t + String.fromCharCode(i) } } t = Base64._utf8_decode(t); return t }, _utf8_encode: function (e) { e = e.replace(/\r\n/g, "n"); var t = ""; for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) { var r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r) } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } else { t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224); t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128); t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128) } } return t }, _utf8_decode: function (e) { var t = ""; var n = 0; var r = c1 = c2 = 0; while (n < e.length) { r = e.charCodeAt(n); if (r < 128) { t += String.fromCharCode(r); n++ } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63); n += 2 } else { c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1); c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2); t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63); n += 3 } } return t } }


var id = 7;

var encodeString = Base64.encode(id.toString());

console.log(encodeString);
```

This encodeString pass to Your controller.

```
http://localhost:60362/ProjectManagement/Project/ProjectSettings/MTA=
```

C# code :

```
 public static string base64Encode(string sData)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encData_byte = new byte[sData.Length];

                encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);

                string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);

                return encodedData;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method To Decrypt Password
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string base64Decode(string sData)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

                System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

                byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);

                int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);

                char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];

                utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);

                string result = new String(decoded_char);

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Final code:

Decryption the value :

```
int id = (int)Convert.ToInt64(Cryptography.base64Decode(orders));
```