# How do I encode a JavaScript string in utf-16?

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, utf-16

In Python 3, I can do this:

```
>>> "€13,56".encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfe\xac 1\x003\x00,\x005\x006\x00'
```

The input is a (unicode) string, while the output is a sequence of raw bytes of that string encoded in utf-16.

How can I do the same in JavaScript - go from a (unicode) string, to a sequence of raw bytes (perhaps as a `Uint8Array`?) of that string encoded in utf-16?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String to Bytearray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray)

Answer (score 13):

Do you want this?

```
function strEncodeUTF16(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2);
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bufView;
}

var arr = strEncodeUTF16('€13,56');
```

Taken from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String)

Comment: I used this to convert a utf8 string (nodejs's default encoding in most cases), into utf16 string (which is the type of default encoding for javascript strings).

Answer (score 2):

```
function strEncodeUTF16(str) {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)
  }
  return arr
}


var arr = strEncodeUTF16('€13,56');

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to convert a utf8 encoded string to a hexadecimal utf-16 string:

```
function dec2hex(dec, padding){
  return parseInt(dec, 10).toString(16).padStart(padding, '0');
}

function utf8StringToUtf16String(str) {
  var utf16 = [];
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    utf16.push(dec2hex(str.charCodeAt(i), 4));
  }
  return utf16.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `Uint8Array`, use this code

> inspired by [shilch's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596748/how-do-i-encode-a-javascript-string-in-utf-16/37597001#37597001)
>
> change `return bufView` to `return new Uint8Array(buf)`

---

```
function strEncodeUTF16(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2);
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Uint8Array(buf);
}

var arr = strEncodeUTF16('€13,56');
```