# How do I convert a string in JavaScript to a sequence of bytes?

Tags: javascript, string

In Python 3, to convert a string to sequence of bytes, one uses `String.encode(ENCODING)` where `ENCODING` is the name of the encoding to use. If I have a character in my string that has a code point greater than 255, then it will still be converted to an array of bytes. This is useful if one needs to operate on the stringfor something like a demo of a cipher. The text can reconstructed by using `ByteArray.decode(ENCODING)`.

I haven't seen anything similar for JavaScript. There is `String.charCodeAt()`, but this would convert a character like `Ā` to `256`. That's not what I want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextEncoder()` `.encode()` and `TextDecoder()` `.decode()` methods

```
let decoder = new TextDecoder(/* character encoding */);
let encoder = new TextEncoder();

let encoded = encoder.encode(str);
let decoded = decoder.decode(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the bytes directly with the standard [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer):

```
var str = "Āabc";
var b = new Blob([str], {type:"text/plain"});
var f = new FileReader();
f.addEventListener("loadend", function(){
    console.log(new Uint8Array(f.result));    // [196, 128, 97, 98, 99]
});
f.readAsArrayBuffer(b);
```

Comment: I'm not using a file.

Comment: @Melab The `FileReader` in the code is reading a blob, not a file. Take a closer look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

"operate on the string for … a cipher": Probably not.

Ciphers are mathematical transformations of byte arrays. The result of encryption is not text so it can't be directly stored in a string.

A JavaScript string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. (Also applies to VB4/5/6, VB, VBA, VBScript, C#, Java….) UTF-16 is one of several encoding of the Unicode character set. UTF-8 is another. Neither encodes to/decodes from arbitrary binary data.

You mentioned `String.charCodeAt()`. This just gives you one of the UTF-16 code units from the string.

Common ways of carrying and displaying binary data in strings are Base64 and hexadecimal. It's a bit weightier that way—and sender and receiver have to agree on both the character encoding of the string and the binary-to-text transformation—but many systems would rather pass text than binary.

Comment: I know that the cryptographic operations are not performed directly on strings. That's why I'm trying to convert between strings and byte arrays. And the result can certainly be stored as a string in Python 3 by using Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: Okay but JavaScript strings are UTF-16. So, do you want to convert the bytes as if they where Latin1 and store them in a string?