# TextEncoder and TextDecoder not perfect inverses of each other

Tags: javascript, string, character-encoding

I received [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47215426) to my previous question about encoding strings. My hope in asking that question was to get some reversible way of shifting between a string and its representation as an array of bytes like in Python 3.

I ran into a problem with one particular Uint8Array though:

```
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var decoder = new TextDecoder(encoder.encoding);
var s = [248, 35, 45, 41, 178, 175, 190, 62, 134, 39];
var t = Array.from(decoder.decode(encoder.encode(Uint8Array(s)));
```

I expected the value of `t` to be `[248, 35, 45, 41, 178, 175, 190, 62, 134, 39]`. Instead, it is `[239, 191, 189, 35, 45, 41, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 62, 239, 191, 189, 39]`. The person who posted the answer was temporarily suspended from the site, so I cannot resolve this through commenting on his answer.

Comment: `s` does not refer to a string so your code doesn't match up to your question. _You aren't trying to process non-text data with a character encoding are you?_ `TextEncoder.encode` expects a string (a sequence of UTF-16 code units), not a `Uint8Array`. The code can be made to work, as @artgb did but there are some obscure coercions going on, including turning an array into a string to pass to `TextEncoder.encode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ArrayBuffer to String then back to ArrayBuffer using TextDecoder/TextEncoder returning a different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198017/converting-arraybuffer-to-string-then-back-to-arraybuffer-using-textdecoder-text)

Answer (score 1):

change `var t = Array.from(decoder.decode(encoder.encode(Uint8Array(s)));` to
 `var t = JSON.parse('['+decoder.decode(encoder.encode(new Uint8Array(s)))+']');`.

```js
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var decoder = new TextDecoder(encoder.encoding);
var s = [248, 35, 45, 41, 178, 175, 190, 62, 134, 39];
var t = JSON.parse('['+decoder.decode(encoder.encode(new Uint8Array(s)))+']');
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?