# TextEncoder and TextDecoder inverse of each other?

Tags: javascript

I'm using TextDecoder to store a random sequence of bytes as a string. Then I want to transform that string back to an ArrayBuffer to give it as an input to WebCrypto API functions.
The problem is that I don't get back the same buffer generated previously. Here's some code to explain it better:

```js
const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
const textDecoder = new TextDecoder();

const buffer = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

// I expect this to contains the same exact bytes of "buffer", but they are different
const recomputedBuffer = textEncoder.encode(textDecoder.decode(buffer));

// Print to see the differences
console.log(buffer);
console.log(recomputedBuffer);
```

Is it a charset mismatch problem or something similiar?

(I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296601) but seems a different problem)

**EDIT (solved):**
I made a mistake using the **text* encoders to encode binary data, they are supposed to work with text and indeed they work with text.
To encode binaries as string `btoa` and `atob` are more appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean under ***equal***? In case of objects, `==` and `===` use reference equality, which (quite obviously) won't work in your case. For compare by value, search for '*Object value equality*' or something similar.

Comment: With equal I mean they should contain the same bytes, but after the trasformations "recomputedBuffer" has different bytes, try to execute the code and print the buffers to check it

Comment: Ok, then I don't know...

Comment: Don't you think that perhaps the fact they're called *Text*Encoder and *Text*Decoder hint at the underlying implementation (and reasonable expectations) I wouldn't expect someone sending a binary file while in text-mode to receive what they sent either. :wink:

Comment: Oh you are right, my mistake, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ArrayBuffer to String then back to ArrayBuffer using TextDecoder/TextEncoder returning a different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198017/converting-arraybuffer-to-string-then-back-to-arraybuffer-using-textdecoder-text)