# How to convert String to Byte array in react native?

Tags: react-native, converters

I know this question asked in different ways but I couldn't find the right answer that fit to react native...

How to convert String to Byte array I react native?

For example I would like the function will be like that:

StringToByteArray('hello')

The output should be something like that:
[72,0,101,0,108,0,108,0,111,0]

I have been looking in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray) post, but it seems the answers are incorrect or invalid...

Comment: @Andrew I have seen that but the answers not for react native and not have enough information

Comment: @Andrew if you were reading the comments you have seen that the answer is incorrect...

Comment: It seems like you are correct, i'll remove my duplication flag. I would suggest updating your post to state that you looked at that answer and that it was wrong

Comment: @Andrew just updated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this solution:

```
function convertStringToByteArray(str) {                                                                                                                                      
  var bytes = [];                                                                                                                                                             
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {                                                                                                                                      
    bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                           
  return bytes                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

The way to use this function:

```
console.log(convertStringToByteArray("Hello"));
// [ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 ]
```