# Encode javascript string bytes as base64

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode, decode, encode

I have a code in c#

```
public static string Encriptar(string _cadenaAencriptar)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    byte[] encodedData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_cadenaAencriptar);
    result = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedData );
    return result;
}
```

I want this code in javaScript.
Helpme please.

Comment: This is *not* encryption... this is *encoding*.  The variable name "encrypted" should be changed to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are taking a utf16 encoded string and converting the utf16 bytes to a Base64 encoded string.

The following JavaScript first converts the string to a array of utf16 bytes.
Then converts the array to a Base64 encoded string.

```
_arrayBufferToBase64(strToUtf16Bytes(_cadenaAencriptar))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458996/361714

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904484/361714

```
function strToUtf16Bytes(str) {
  const bytes = [];
  for (ii = 0; ii < str.length; ii++) {
    const code = str.charCodeAt(ii); // x00-xFFFF
    bytes.push(code & 255, code >> 8); // low, high
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Output from javascript:

```
_arrayBufferToBase64(strToUtf16Bytes("hi"))
"aABpAA=="
```

Which matches the output from C#.