# Python 3.8 TypeError: can't concat str to bytes - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, irc

Very new to coding. This was the initial code I was trying to get to run but have found it is incompatible with python 3 because of how it handles strings and bytes.

```
def opensocket():
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect((HOST,PORT))
     s.send("PASS " + PASS + "\r\n")
     s.send("NICK " + IDENT + "\r\n")
     s.send("JOIN #" + CHANNEL + "\r\n")
     return s
```

I think I need to encode these strings into bytes but all the conversion methods I've tried have given errors. here are some i've tried.

```
def opensocket():
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect((HOST,PORT))
     s.send(b"PASS " + PASS + "\r\n")
     s.send(b"NICK " + IDENT + "\r\n")
     s.send(b"JOIN #" + CHANNEL + "\r\n")
```

and

```
def opensocket():
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect((HOST,PORT))
     s.send("PASS " + PASS + "\r\n".encode())
     s.send("NICK " + IDENT + "\r\n".encode())
     s.send("JOIN #" + CHANNEL + "\r\n".encode())
     return s
```

both of these give errors saying the str can't be concatenated into bytes
any help?

edit: went through the suggested post but I'm gaining nothing from that. it looks so different and I'm so new to this that I can't even tell where the string was he was trying to convert

Comment: What is the type of PASS, IDENT, CHANNEL ? to get it use type(PASS)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a String to Bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray)

Comment: @M-Chen-3: that post is irrelevant here since it's for C#. OP's problem is in Python.

Comment: @Basil Okay, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `PASS`, `IDENT` and `CHANNEL` are `bytes`:

```
def opensocket():
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect((HOST,PORT))
     s.send(b"PASS " + PASS + b"\r\n")
     s.send(b"NICK " + IDENT + b"\r\n")
     s.send(b"JOIN #" + CHANNEL + b"\r\n")
```

In the case that `PASS`, `IDENT` and `CHANNEL` are `str`:

```
def opensocket():
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect((HOST,PORT))
     s.send(b"PASS " + PASS.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
     s.send(b"NICK " + IDENT.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
     s.send(b"JOIN #" + CHANNEL.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
```

It's important to know what protocol you're using, to know what encoding actually to use. `'ascii'` is a safe bet, but it means you're limited in to ASCII-only characters, so if the protocol actually specifies UTF-8 strings, you should do `.encode('utf-8')` instead.