# Using SharedArrayBuffer with objects

Tags: javascript

Examples I can find online of using `SharedArrayBuffer` all seem to be stupid simple, like setting a single byte in the buffer array and then sharing that. But those examples are extremely impractical because no one ever works with raw binary data. No one is every going to do:

```js
myArrayBuffer[0] = 12;
```

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
const sharedArray = new SharedArrayBuffer();
const big64Array = new BigUint64Array(sharedArray);

const entry = {
    Hash: (213874914491n).toString(), // manually toString here because bigint isn't serializable
    BestMove: 10493,
    Depth: 3,
    Score: 41,
    Flag: 0,
};

// I want to put `entry` into big64Array. Ideally, I'd do:
big64Array[0] = BigInt(entry);

// Other things I've tried...
const big64Array = new BigUint64Array(entry); // = [];
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(entry); // = [];
const uint8ArrayFromText = new Uint8Array(new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(entry))); // gives an actual byte array

// Apparently this works:
const view = new DataView(uint8ArrayFromText.buffer, 0);
big64Array[0] = view.getBigUint64(0, true);
// But the above seems very...contrived. And I'll need to use a different DataView to convert it back, which I haven't figured out how to do.
```

Performance is also extremely important here, so if the only way to do this is by calling multiple methods and/or converting a property between various different things this might not work.

Comment: "_no one ever works with raw binary data_": I work with it almost every day.

Comment: "_Do I have to convert the object to a binary string myself?_": Yes (or use an existing library — e.g. [msgpack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack), [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript))

Comment: You could also just `JSON.stringify` it and convert that string to bytes, if the object supports JSON serialization.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, serialization is usually the easy direction, but OP would have to implement deserialization themselves. (Not necessarily "harder", but just a bit more code)

Comment: @jsejcksn Not if they use `TextEncode`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762658/215552 and `JSON.parse`. I mean, they'd have to call those functions in the right order, but they'd have to do that with any other library too :). Might not be as efficient as the others though, TBH, but they're built in.

Comment: The `TextEncoder` method I've tried, but the only issue with it is that it returns a `Uint8Array`, while I'd like a `BigUint64Array`.

Comment: @Kurt If you update the details of you question to be [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including showing an example of `HashFlag`) then I can try to provide an answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not that simple with non-primitive types because they don't have native de-/serializations.

Comment: @jsejcksn Hence why I said "if the object support JSON serialization"...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well, the question details already include information about a "bigint" which isn't JSON-serializable...

Comment: @jsejcksn, I've added a bit more of an example of what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Kurt In the original question details, you described `entry.BestMove` as a `number`, but in the update it's a `string`. Can you update the question details to include a single example which actually represents the scenario? Also, is `entry.Flag` an enum or an arbitrary string? (In a re-usable buffer, you must allocate a fixed number of bytes for each `string`, so knowing the maximum length of a string value can help with efficiency.)

Comment: @jsejcksn, sorry, my brain is pretty fried trying to figure this out. Is the edit any better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to an example, first I'll discuss a bit of context regarding the details of your question:

When serializing native data (in your question: JS native data types) into a binary format that's in shared memory (and deserializing it somewhere else), you always need to know the number of bytes required by each part of your data structure.

In the details of your question, you show a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and some [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) types. In JavaScript, a number is always a [double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), and when dealing with integers, the max number value is [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (`2 ** 53 -1`).

When looking at the [typed arrays in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), this max integer value is too large be representable as a single element in any of them except the 64-bit variants. This means that, in order to represent *any* JS number in each typed array element, you must allocate 64-bits (or 8 bytes) for each number. However: if you are certain that the possible values of a number type will never exceed some smaller limit, then you can store that value more efficiently by allocating less memory (fewer bytes) for it. For example: if the number will never exceed 8 bits (e.g. it's always in the range of `0` to `255` in the case of unsigned integers, or `-128` to `127` for singed ints), then you can allocate a single byte for it instead of 8 bytes. Or if it's in the range of a 16-bit number (e.g. `0` to `65535` unsigned, or `-32768` to `32767` signed), then you can simply allocate 2 bytes for it.

Because you didn't provide this information in your question, I've made some arbitrary choices for you in the example below, assuming that `entry.BestMove` will be 16-bit unsigned and the other `number` types will be 8-bit unsigned. If this is not the case for your actual data, then you can adjust the information accordingly, but I've chosen this to show some variety.

In addition to typed arrays, JS also offers an interface for reading and writing specific number types in a binary `ArrayBuffer`: the [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView). In the example below, I demonstrate how to use a data view with a struct like the one in your question. I've provided lots of inline comments, but if you're still uncertain about something after reading through it (and all of the links I've provided above), feel free to leave a comment.

```js
'use strict';

// See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
// Whether this is set to true or false doesn't really matter —
// it only needs to be applied consistently when accessing the binary slices
// which occupy greater than 1 byte:
const littleEndian = true;

// A map of encoded information about each entry component:
// - its byte length
// - its starting byte index in a binary array buffer
// - a method for writing its associated value to a data view
// - a method for retrieving its associated value from a data view
const entryBinaryMap = {
  Hash: {
    byteLength: 8,
    index: 0, // first index is 0
    set (dataView, bigint) {
      dataView.setBigUint64(this.index, bigint, littleEndian);
    },
    get (dataView) {
      return dataView.getBigUint64(this.index, littleEndian);
    },
  },
  BestMove: {
    byteLength: 2,
    index: 8, // previous index + previous byte length
    set (dataView, number) {
      dataView.setUint16(this.index, number, littleEndian);
    },
    get (dataView) {
      return dataView.getUint16(this.index, littleEndian);
    },
  },
  Depth: {
    byteLength: 1,
    index: 10, // previous index + previous byte length
    set (dataView, number) {
      dataView.setUint8(this.index, number);
    },
    get (dataView) {
      return dataView.getUint8(this.index);
    },
  },
  Score: {
    byteLength: 1,
    index: 11, // previous index + previous byte length
    set (dataView, number) {
      dataView.setUint8(this.index, number);
    },
    get (dataView) {
      return dataView.getUint8(this.index);
    },
  },
  Flag: {
    byteLength: 1,
    index: 12, // previous index + previous byte length
    set (dataView, number) {
      dataView.setUint8(this.index, number);
    },
    get (dataView) {
      return dataView.getUint8(this.index);
    },
  },
  BYTE_LENGTH: 13, // previous index + previous byte length = total bytes
};

// Use the map methods to apply the entry data to the buffer:
function serialize (buffer, entry) {
  const view = new DataView(buffer);
  entryBinaryMap.Hash.set(view, entry.Hash);
  entryBinaryMap.BestMove.set(view, entry.BestMove);
  entryBinaryMap.Depth.set(view, entry.Depth);
  entryBinaryMap.Flag.set(view, entry.Flag);
  entryBinaryMap.Score.set(view, entry.Score);
}

// Get the individual entry values using the map methods:
function deserialize (buffer) {
  const view = new DataView(buffer);
  return {
    Hash: entryBinaryMap.Hash.get(view),
    BestMove: entryBinaryMap.BestMove.get(view),
    Depth: entryBinaryMap.Depth.get(view),
    Flag: entryBinaryMap.Flag.get(view),
    Score: entryBinaryMap.Score.get(view),
  };
}

// Make it even more convenient to use:
function serde (buffer, entry) {
  return entry ? serialize(buffer, entry) : deserialize(buffer);
}

// I'm using a regular ArrayBuffer here because the Stack Overflow code snippet
// sandbox doesn't allow for SharedArrayBuffers, but it works the same with both:
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(entryBinaryMap.BYTE_LENGTH);
// const buffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(entryBinaryMap.BYTE_LENGTH);

const entry = {
  Hash: 213874914491n,
  BestMove: 10493,
  Depth: 3,
  Score: 41,
  Flag: 0,
};

// Serialize to the buffer:
serde(buffer, entry);

// Deserialize from the buffer:
const deserializedEntry = serde(buffer);

// Validate that the values are equal:
const equal = [
  deserializedEntry.Hash === entry.Hash,
  deserializedEntry.BestMove === entry.BestMove,
  deserializedEntry.Depth === entry.Depth,
  deserializedEntry.Score === entry.Score,
  deserializedEntry.Flag === entry.Flag,
].every(Boolean);

console.log(equal); // true
```

Note that using the map object in the example above is a bit ceremonial, but I included it to help conspicuously illustrate the relationships in the data since you seem to be learning about working with binary data in JavaScript. There are certainly other approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: Man, I was so close to this. My implementation actually uses a much larger ArrayBuffer (32+ MB) to store multiple entries. Your answer got me past my blocks and I actually managed to get that working. Unfortunately, it's WAY slower compared to just storing the object in an array (which, also unfortunately, can't be shared with workers).

Comment: @Kurt I’m not sure what you’re doing with 32+ MB of binary data entries, but it sounds like a lot of iterative work. You might want to consider sharing the buffer with a wasm function for a potential speed increase. If you go that route, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), of course, instead of modifying this one.