# What is the typescript/javascript equivalent of java string.getBytes()?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a java line of code that I want to convert to typescript.

```
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/vcard".getBytes(), new byte[] {}, messagebytes);
```

NdefRecord is a function that takes the following parameters: (tnf:number,type:string|number[],id:string|number[],payload:string|number[])

I tried several approaches to writing getBytes alternatives in typescript:

```
var vcard= `BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\nN:;${firstName}\nORG: ${org}\nEMAIL:${email}\nEND:VCARD`;
var payload = this.nfc.stringToBytes(vcard)
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var array = Array.from(encoder.encode("text/vcard"))
```

1:

```
record = this.ndef.record(tnf, array, [], payload);
```

2:

```
record = this.ndef.record(tnf, encoder.encode("text/vcard").toString(), [], payload);
```

3:

```
record = this.ndef.record(tnf, this.nfc.stringToBytes("text/vcard"), [], payload);
```

The first and third approaches yield a JSON error, whereas the second returns the contents of the vcard as a string.
Is there any way to get the bytes of the record type "text/vcard"?

Comment: I don't know Java, but a quick search suggest that Java's `string.getBytes()` does something similar to JS's `[...string].map(char => char.charCodeAt())`.

Comment: `Array.from(encoder.encode("text/vcard"))` [should work in order to get the byte array out of that string](https://jsbin.com/nuhodudite/edit?js,console). I'm not sure where and how exactly you experience a problem with it.

Comment: There is already a question and answers posted to this topic. How to convert a string to Bytearray in javascript. Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762658/5012127