# String to byte array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have to convert a string to byte (16 bit) in JavaScript. I can do this in .net in following code but I have to change this for old classic asp App which uses JavaScript.

```
string strShared_Key = "6fc2e550abc4ea333395346123456789";
int nLength = strShared_Key.Length;
byte[] keyMAC = new byte[nLength / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < nLength; i += 2)
    keyMAC[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(strShared_Key.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

This is the JavaScript function but doesn't return same out put as above .net code.

```
function String2Bin16bit(inputString) {
        var str = ""; // string 
        var arr = [];       // byte array 
        for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i += 2) {
            // get chunk of two characters and parse to number 
            arr.push(parseInt(inputString.substr(i, 2), 16));
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/HTML - converting byte array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/javascript-html-converting-byte-array-to-string) Question/Solution has both ways of doing it.

Comment: epascarello - this example doesn not work for 16 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `parseInt(x, 16)` which will read `x` as a number and parse it as such bearing in mind that it's in base 16.

```
var str = "aabbcc"; // string
var arr = [];       // byte array
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    arr.push(parseInt(str.substr(i, 2), 16)); // get chunk of two characters and parse to number
}
```

Comment: I tried writing following function but did not output the exact value what I get in .net function.    
function String2Bin16bit(inputString) {
    //var str = "aabbcc"; // string 
    var arr = [];       // byte array 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i += 2) {
        // get chunk of two characters and parse to number 
        arr[i / 2] = arr.push(parseInt(inputString.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return arr;
}

Comment: Is that JavaScript? You're using `arr[i / 2] = arr.push`, which does not make sense. `arr.push` simply adds the value to the array, so no need for indices.

Comment: Yes it is javascript, still results are not same like .net function.  I changed to 
function String2Bin16bit(inputString) {
    var str = ""; // string 
    var arr = [];       // byte array 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i += 2) {
        // get chunk of two characters and parse to number 
        arr.push(parseInt(inputString.substr(i, 2), 16));
         // str = str + arr.push(parseInt(inputString.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return arr;
}

Comment: @user228777: What about posting it in your question, since it's inscrutable without formatting in comments please.

Comment: I added javascript function in my original post now.

Comment: @user228777: It works fine for me. What differences are there in the results?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3657/discussion-between-user228777-and-pimvdb)

Comment: Eventually I have to write above javascript function ( calculating 16 bit ) in this format: function str2binl(str) { var bin = Array(); var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1; for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz) bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i%32); return bin; }