# How to decode byte of array data using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, decode

I have the following type of data. It is an array of bytes data  getting after Ajax request calls to server. Server encodes respective file and returns this data as response. Now I have to decode that data in string format using JavaScript. How can I do that? please help me.

```
67,37,94,38,42,44,69,67,71,32,97,116,116,97,99,104,101,100,32,102,111,114,32,112,
97,116,105,101,110,116,32,45,32,71,82,65,72,65,77,44,32,77,65,82,89,13,10,72,37,
94,38,42,44,49,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,51,47,49,52,47,50,48,49,51,32,49,50,58,50,
57,58,52,55,32,80,77,44,44,13,10,77,37,94,38,42,44,77..
```

Comment: Decode it how? From a string into an array? From an array into a string? From JSON to JavaScript? More info needed I'm afraid.

Comment: byte of arry to string.that is original format.

Comment: `var ar = JSON.parse('[' + comma_separated +']')`

Comment: @rab: you are not getting my question.actually above data is in encoded form from server side.now I have to decode using javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/javascript-html-converting-byte-array-to-string