# get back a string representation from computeDigest(algorithm, value) byte[]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, md5, digest

The Google App Script function computeDigest returns a byte array of the signature. How can I get the string representation of the digest?

I have already tried the bin2String() function.

```
function sign(){     
var signature = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, "thisisteststring")
Logger.log(bin2String(signature));
}


function bin2String(array) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(array[i], 2));
  }
  return result;
}
```

but it puts "" in the Logs

Comment: you need to post what you have tried.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If we put `Logger.log(signature);` right after the call to `computeDigest()`, we get:

```
[8, 30, -43, 124, -101, 114, -37, 10, 78, -13, -102, 51, 65, -24, -83, 81]
```

As represented in javascript, the digest includes both positive and negative integers, so we can't simply treat them as ascii characters. The MD5 algorithm, however, should provide us with 8-bit values, in the range 0x00 to 0xFF (255). Those negative values, then, are just a misinterpretation of the high-order bit; taking it to be a sign bit. To correct, we need to add 256 to any negative value.

[How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript) gives us this for retrieving hex characters:

```
hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);
```

Putting that together, here's your `sign()` function, which is also [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/5464686):

```
function sign(message){     
  message = message || "thisisteststring";
  var signature = Utilities.computeDigest(
                       Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5,
                       message,
                       Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII);
  Logger.log(signature);
  var signatureStr = '';
    for (i = 0; i < signature.length; i++) {
      var byte = signature[i];
      if (byte < 0)
        byte += 256;
      var byteStr = byte.toString(16);
      // Ensure we have 2 chars in our byte, pad with 0
      if (byteStr.length == 1) byteStr = '0'+byteStr;
      signatureStr += byteStr;
    }   
  Logger.log(signatureStr);
  return signatureStr;
}
```

And here's what the logs contain:

```
[13-04-25 21:46:55:787 EDT] [8, 30, -43, 124, -101, 114, -37, 10, 78, -13, -102, 51, 65, -24, -83, 81]
[13-04-25 21:46:55:788 EDT] 081ed57c9b72db0a4ef39a3341e8ad51
```

Let's see what we get from [this on-line MD5 Hash Generator](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php):

[image: 081ed57c9b72db0a4ef39a3341e8ad51]

I tried it with a few other strings, and they consistently matched the result from the on-line generator.

Answer (score 17):

Just in case this is helpful to anyone else, I've put together a more succinct version of Mogsdad's solution:

```
function md5(str) {
  return Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, str).reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },'');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One-liner:

```
Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, "teststring")
  .map(function(b) {return ("0" + (b < 0 && b + 256 || b).toString(16)).substr(-2)})
  .join("")
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how this works? In the interest of educating future readers.

Comment: 1) "map" takes each byte in array returned by "computeDigest" and performs some transformation on it.

2) "(b < 0 && b + 256 || b)" - && takes precedence over || so it actually looks like this: ( (b < 0 && b + 256) || b ). It says "If b < 0, give b+256, otherwise give b". 

3) ".toString(16)" Convert the corrected "b" value to hex string

4) "0" + hex string (in case b is less than 16, e.g. if b is 1 then: "0"+"1" -> "01". In case b is 16 or more we get "010". But we just want two chars so

5) "substr(-2)" take last two chars

6) join together

Comment: In fact you don't need conditionals:
inputArray.map(function(b) {return ("0"+((b+256)%256).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");

Answer (score 7):

Did somebody say succinct? (*/fulldecent arrives to party with the drinking hat, including straws, after everyone else already passed out*)

```
Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, "thisisteststring")
  .map(function(chr){return (chr+256).toString(16).slice(-2)})
  .join('')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to transform a Byte[] into a String.

Found this in the documentation provided by Google here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Decode(String)

```
Utilities.newBlob(myByteArray).getDataAsString();
```

Better late than never. (And since this topic still comes first when searching this topic in Goole, this might help some folks).

Answer (score -1):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195961/205426):

```
function string2Bin(str) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result.push(str.charCodeAt(i).toString(2));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: well actually it is bin2string. But I have already tried that. and it doesn't work. Try it for yourself.