# double hashing sha256 NOTworking!! + how to convert to hex?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

so I've been trying to mirror the double hashing using SHA256 in Google Script, and I am not able to replicate the second hash.  The first one gets replicated correctly, but then something must be off with that first hash being plugged into the next digest.

```
  var teststring = "hello";

  var firsthash=Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, teststring); 

  var secondhash=Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, firsthash);

  app.getElementById('balancelabel').setText("result: "+secondhash);
```

I then look up first hash and second hash on an online converter.  First hash matches the below expectation, and the second doesn't.  I have tried so many things to try to modify firsthash variable but can't seem to make it work.

This is what the hashes should be:
hello
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824 (first round of sha-256)
9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50 (second round of sha-256)

I have also been trying really hard to get that byte hash and produce a hex encoded string (not base64, which Google Script does seem to support out of the box).

Can someone PLEASE HELP?

EDIT:  It appears impossible using Utitilies.computeDigest because it only accepts string as input.  However, I just checked that I can implement this JS sha256 function in Google Script.  How would I do a double hash using byte input of the first hash?

[SHA256 JavaScript function](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html)

Comment: Looks like you are giving the hex-encoded first result to the second hash, not the raw result, i.e. `sha256(hex(sha256(x))` instead of `sha256(sha256(x))`

Comment: Hmmm, so how do I get the raw result?  I thought Utilities.computeDigest returns the raw result in byte form.

Comment: I don't know. I was just guessing that it is encoded since you directly `setText` the secondhash.

Comment: Actually, that returns a byte array.

Comment: True. I looked at the docs now. computeDigest takes a String input. Not sure if it can be made to work with binary data.

Comment: Are you sure about that expected result? I get something different, using the same tool - maybe you had an extra character after pasting?

Answer (score 3):

```
function sign(message){
message = message || "thisisteststring";
var signature = Utilities.computeDigest(
                Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1,
                message,
                Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII);
Logger.log(signature);
var signatureStr = '';
for (i = 0; i < signature.length; i++) {
   var byte = signature[i];
    if (byte < 0)
      byte += 256;
var byteStr = byte.toString(16);
// Ensure we have 2 chars in our byte, pad with 0
if (byteStr.length == 1) byteStr = '0'+byteStr;
signatureStr += byteStr;
}

 Logger.log(signatureStr);
return signatureStr;
}
```

You Can you this function for converting string to your disired format

Answer (score 0):

There was a related question recently: [get back a string representation from computeDigest(algorithm, value) byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216868/get-back-a-string-representation-from-computedigestalgorithm-value-byte).

I [modified the gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/5464686) with the answer from that question, and it now includes a function to return a string digest using sha256.

```
var teststring = "hello";
var result = signSHA_256(signSHA_256(teststring));
// d7914fe546b684688bb95f4f888a92dfc680603a75f23eb823658031fff766d9
```

#### Result from online tool

The result from the double-digest call matches the result from the [online generator](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html).

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for taking time to look into this.  However, this is the result I have been getting all along, which is wrong.  Apparently, the "d7..." hash is not a hash of the first hash, but is a hash of a string representation of the first hash, which are two different things.  The second hash should be the "95.." one. The problem seems to be stemming from the fact that I am unable to feed the byte representation of the first hash into the second SHA digest. Your hex string representation implementation, though, is what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: @user145453 - Maybe you will find some help [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=62). It suggests using Latin1 charset for binary, to avoid default mapping to UTF-8.