# Hmac Signing in Google Apps Script, When Secret and Digest are base64 encoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, base64, hmac

Given this code in nodejs:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const message = 'message to sign';
const secret = 'mysecret';
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(message).digest('hex');
console.log(signature);
```

The output is `40d4c57eed56968de0f3a22e73ebf8abc6ab4c38bba95fd2c85dd4dc90bf36b9`

With the help of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216868/get-back-a-string-representation-from-computedigestalgorithm-value-byte), I have exactly replicated this behavior in Google Apps Script, with this function:

```
//conversion from byte array taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933459
function makeHmacSignature(macAlg, message, secret) {
  return Utilities.computeHmacSignature(macAlg, message, secret).reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },'');
}
```

HOWEVER, suppose the signing is changed slightly, such that the secret is a base64 encoded string, and we expect the digest in base64. In the nodejs code, the changes are trivial:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const message = 'message to sign';
const secret = 'mysecret';
const decodedSecret = Buffer(secret, 'base64');
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', decodedSecret).update(message).digest('base64');
console.log(signature);
```

Giving the output `bBLhyGY61BPEbPiFKknX1g9eXv9r98uvwwgVy7YMYDY=`

I've been trying for hours, I cannot figure out how to replicate this behavior in Google Apps Script!

Answer (score 6):

Google Apps Script actually has a utility function for this.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue-key

So instead of

```
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(message).digest('hex');
```

you could do this:

```
var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, secret);
// convert byte array to hex string
var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
  chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
  return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
},'');
```

Answer (score 1):

I never successfully figured out how to do this purely with Google Apps Script native functions.

I used [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA). I pasted in the [optimized sha256.js](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha256.js) file, and with that inline, using the example data above, this test function returns the correct output:

```
function testHmacSigs() {
  var message = 'message to sign';
  var secret = 'mysecret';
  var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT");
  shaObj.setHMACKey(secret, "B64");
  shaObj.update(message);
  var sig = shaObj.getHMAC("B64");

  Logger.log(sig);
}
```

Comment: optimised file doesn't exist.  is there a better way to find it or get it?  Don't know much javascript.