# Mimic this Erlang code behaviour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, erlang

I'm trying to obtain in Javascript the same value returned by the following generate_hash erlang function

```
-define(b2l(V), binary_to_list(V)).
-define(l2b(V), list_to_binary(V)).

generate_hash(User, Secret, TimeStamp) ->
    SessionData = User ++ ":" ++ erlang:integer_to_list(TimeStamp, 16),
    Hash = crypto:sha_mac(Secret, SessionData),
    base64:encode(SessionData ++ ":" ++ ?b2l(Hash)).

make_time() ->
    {NowMS, NowS, _} = erlang:now(),
    NowMS * 1000000 + NowS.
```

This function is being called in erlang in this way:

```
Username = "username" 
Secret = ?l2b("secret"),
UserSalt = "usersalt",
CurrentTime = make_time(),
Hash = generate_hash( ?b2l(UserName), <<Secret/binary, UserSalt/binary>>, CurrentTime).
```

I managed to use the google CryptoJS library to calculate the hash, **but the base64 returned value does not match the one returned in erlang**.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>

function generate_hash(User, Secret, TimeStamp) {
    var SessionData = User + ":" + parseInt(TimeStamp,16);
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(Secret,SessionData);
    return atob(SessionData + ":" + hash.toString())
}

var Hash = generate_hash( "username", "secret"+"usersalt", new Date().getTime())

alert(Hash);
```

Comment: maybe stupid, but are you sure to use the same timestamp

Comment: i tried by using seconds, milliseconds and microseconds bu the result is always not the same as in erlang..

Comment: I'm afraid the problem relies in what the "<<Secret/binary, UserSalt/binary>>" piece means in Erlang.. I'm afraid it isn't equal to the simple javascript string concatenation

Comment: @mlorini: This "<<Secret/binary, UserSalt/binary>>" code is exactly, what you need, this is concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems in your code.

Firstly: `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(Secret,SessionData);` has its arguments reversed. It should be `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(SessionData, Secret);`.

You can check it out in JS console:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("b", "a");
0: 1717011798
1: -2038285946
2: -931908057
3: 823367506
4: 21804555
```

Now, go to Erlang console and type this:

```
crypto:sha_mac(<<"a">>, <<"b">>).
<<102,87,133,86,134,130,57,134,200,116,54,39,49,19,151,82,1,76,182,11>>
binary:encode_unsigned(1717011798).
<<102,87,133,86>>
binary:encode_unsigned(21804555).
<<1,76,182,11>>
```

I don't know equivalent method for signed integers, but this proves, that changing the order of arguments gives the same binary value.

Second problem is with `hash.toString()`, which following my example gives something like:

```
hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("b", "a");
hash.toString();
"6657855686823986c874362731139752014cb60b"
```

while Erlang binary to list will result in:

```
Str = binary_to_list(Hash).
[102,87,133,86,134,130,57,134,200,116,54,39,49,19,151,82,1,76,182,11]
io:format("~s", [Str]).
fWV9Èt6'1^SR^AL¶^K
```

I am not sure, what toString does with word array, but this messes up the final result.

Third problem is, that `new Date().getTime()` will return time in milliseconds, while in Erlang, you have microseconds. This shouldn't matter, when you test it with static integer, though.

Comment: @mlorini hash.toString() creates hexadecimal string representation. You can get it in erlang with `lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~2.16.0b", [Byte]) || <<Byte:8>> <= Hash]).`

Comment: I think that @mlorini wants the opposite - to create the Erlang representation with JS. @Łukasz: do you know, how to convert JS list of words to something like Erlang string after `binary_to_list`?

Comment: exactly. I want the opposite!

Comment: @mlorini Sorry, found answer for your problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3195961/4169859 but I'm not sure how it is going to handle non ascii values...

Comment: @tkowal yeah, thanks to your suggestions, this fiddle produces in javascript the same byte sequence of the erlang counterpart:  https://jsfiddle.net/ou0wknwv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The `make_time` function in the Erlang code above returns the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch, while the Javascript method `getTime` returns the number of *milliseconds*.

   Besides that, since you're probably not running the two functions in the same second, you'll get different timestamps and therefore different hashes anyway.
2. The Javascript function `parseInt` parses a string and returns an integer, while the Erlang function `integer_to_list` takes an integer and converts it to a string (in Erlang, strings are represented as lists, thus the name).  You probably want to use the `toString` method instead.

Comment: yes, I mean by running this function at the same time.. For test of course, i'm using a fixed value for timestamp..

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm can generate the same sequence of bytes generated by `erlang` counterpart:

```
var ret = [];

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("b","a").words;
angular.forEach(hash,function(v){
    var pos = v>=0, last=ret.length;
    for(v=pos?v:v>>>0; v>0; v=Math.floor(v/256)) {
        ret.splice(last, 0, v%256);
    }
});
console.info(ret);
console.info(String.fromCharCode.apply(String,ret));
```

The above outputs:

```
[102, 87, 133, 86, 134, 130, 57, 134, 200, 116, 54, 39, 49, 19, 151, 82, 1, 76, 182, 11]
fWV9Èt6'1RL¶
```