# Convert bytearray into String using data binding in AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In Java code I can easily convert `bytearray` into `String` like this:

```
byte[] data = {91, 123};
String string = new String(data);
```

But it is giving problems in doing the same with AngularJS in a data binding:

```
{{new String(data)}}
```

The above code is inside a HTML file of AngularJS code and the `data` is coming as a bytearray from an API call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3195961

Comment: the easiest is to convert the bytearray to string in the api call itself, and just use the string in the databinding

Comment: Do you know the difference between Java and JavaScript? (Your post suggests you do, but just to be sure.) Also, can you change the API or are you just consuming it?

Comment: @11684 - sorry, I don't know much about javascript. The api can be modified but I thought if there may be easy way to do it in angularjs itself as in java. Some restrictions are there because I am passing the bean object of API and in angularjs I am just retrieving the object properties by its getter methods so its difficult to change the object's getter method just for this change as I am using it in other files of my java application.

Comment: @SajanChandran - See above comment for the same reason.

Comment: I just wanted to ascertain you know that Java and JavaScript are two entirely different languages, you wouldn't be the first to ask a question on SO thinking that those are the same. What do you see when you try to `console.log()` the raw byte array (in JavaScript, of course)? What is its type? (`typeof data`)