# js how to convert a string of 0 and 1 to a byte

Tags: javascript, binary, byte, bit

How to convert a string to a byte in javascript and vice-versa?

**Sample:**

```
a = "10101010";
b = toByte(a); //char(170)

backtoBin(b); //10101010
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting byte array to string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/converting-byte-array-to-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

binary to integer

```
integer = parseInt(binary,2);
```

integer to binary

```
binary = integer.toString(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **[toString(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toString)** you can convert a number to its binary value, to revert it you can use **[parseInt(binaryValue, 2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Example:_Using_parseInt)**. You could do it this way:

```js
function toByte(str){
  return parseInt(str, 2);
}
function backtoBin(num){
  return num.toString(2);
}

var a = "10101010";
var b = toByte(a); //170
var c = backtoBin(b); //10101010

console.log(b, c)
```

```html
<script src="http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt(a, 2)` with radix of 2 to convert the string to a value

```
a = "1010101010";
b = parseInt(a, 2); // results in b = 170
```

And use `Number(b).toString(2)` to convert the integer to string

```
b = 170;
a = Number(b).toString(2); // results a = "10101010";
```