# Convert a ByteStream to CSV Format

Tags: javascript, csv, bytestream

```
{
"report": "IkFncmVlbWVudCBObyIsIkxlYXNlIEV4cCBEYXRlIiwiTmFtZSBPZiBMZXNlZSIsIkVuZ2luZSBObyIsIkNoYXNzaXMgTm8iLCJSZWcuIE51bWJlciIsIkFtdC4gRmluYW5jZWQiLCJNb250aGx5IFJlbnQiLCJQZXJpb2QiLCJSZW50IFBhaWQiLCJQYWlkIFZhbHVlIiwiRlJSIiwibnVsbCUgRlJSIiwiQnJhbmNoIiwiUmVudGFscyBSY3ZkIiwiQXJyZWFycyA+IDIgbW9udGhzIiwiRGlzdHJpY3QiLAoibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCJudWxsIiwibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCJudWxsIiwiMC4wIiwiMC4wIiwibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCIwLjAiLCIwLjAiLCIwLjAiLCJudWxsIiwiMC4wIiwiMC4wIiwibnVsbCIs",
"fileName": "TrancheReport.csv"
}
```

I got a byte stream like the above and it needs to be converted in to string with javascript. Could anyone help with the above scenario ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16245767/215552 to convert the base64 string to a byte array, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/3195865/215552 to convert the byte array to a string (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542820/215552) for its brevity).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) that decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding.

```js
var json = {
  "report": "IkFncmVlbWVudCBObyIsIkxlYXNlIEV4cCBEYXRlIiwiTmFtZSBPZiBMZXNlZSIsIkVuZ2luZSBObyIsIkNoYXNzaXMgTm8iLCJSZWcuIE51bWJlciIsIkFtdC4gRmluYW5jZWQiLCJNb250aGx5IFJlbnQiLCJQZXJpb2QiLCJSZW50IFBhaWQiLCJQYWlkIFZhbHVlIiwiRlJSIiwibnVsbCUgRlJSIiwiQnJhbmNoIiwiUmVudGFscyBSY3ZkIiwiQXJyZWFycyA+IDIgbW9udGhzIiwiRGlzdHJpY3QiLAoibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCJudWxsIiwibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCJudWxsIiwiMC4wIiwiMC4wIiwibnVsbCIsIm51bGwiLCIwLjAiLCIwLjAiLCIwLjAiLCJudWxsIiwiMC4wIiwiMC4wIiwibnVsbCIs",
  "fileName": "TrancheReport.csv"
};

var str = atob(json.report);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys!:)))

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.