# Exif-Parser in Node, extract XPComment, XPKeyword tag values

Tags: nodes, exif

While, using [Exif-Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-parser/tutorial) in Node, fetching Tag values of XPComment, XPKeywords seem to be an Array(unsure what the type  is). I want to log these tag values How to get it in a readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the XPComment and XPKeywords are parsed as Byte array, This can be converted to String value using String.fromCharCode.

For example:
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [102, 111, 111]) equals 'foo'.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542820/2011046