# Converting a larger byte array to a string

Tags: javascript

When `N` is set to `125K` the following works

```
let N = 125000
let x = [...Array(N)].map(( xx,i) => i)
let y = String.fromCodePoint(...x)
console.log(y.length)
```

When N is set to `128K` that same code breaks:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This is a common operation: what is the optimal way to achieve the conversion?

Note that I did look at this related Q&A . https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195961/1056563   We should not depend on `node.js` and also the approaches with the `fromCharCode.apply` are failing.  Finally that answer is nearly ten years old.

So what is an up to date performant way to handle this conversion?

Comment: Interesting. Avoiding the `...` (in the call to `String.fromCodePoint`?) will probably get around that issue. That is, I suspect it's related to passing too many arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/2864740

Comment: oh !  that's a good point! Feel free to make an answer. It's not really a _full_ answer but it points the right direction and I would upvote

Comment: It still won't work as fromCodePoint doesn't take an array :( Just trying to really isolate the observed issue. The larger question is still there: "How to [efficiently] create a string from a very large sequence of code points?"

Comment: Yes it will not - but you are correct to realize that the parameter passing will not work either. I am looking into alternatives

Comment: Does using ‘call’ instead of the ‘...’ change the behavior? That might be an implement detail, depending on how such code unifies internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because *implementations* have *limits* to the [number of parameters accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/2864740). This results in an exception being raised when too many parameters (over ~128k in this case) are supplied to the `String.fromCodePoint` functions via the spread operator.

One way to solve this problem *relatively efficiently*, albeit with slightly more code, is to batch the operation across multiple calls. Here is my proposed implementation, which fixes what I perceive as issues relating to scaling performance <del>and the handling of [surrogate pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)</del> (that's incorrect: `fromCodePoint` doesn't care about surrogates, making it preferable to `fromCharCode` in such cases).

```
let N = 500 * 1000;
let A = [...Array(N)].map((x,i) => i); // start with "an array".

function codePointsToString(cps) {
  let rs = [];
  let batch = 32767; // Supported 'all' browsers
  for (let i = 0; i < cps.length; ){
    let e = i + batch;
    // Build batch section, defer to Array.join.
    rs.push(String.fromCodePoint.apply(null, cps.slice(i, e)));
    i = e;
  }
  return rs.join('');
}

var result = codePointsToString(A);
console.log(result.length);
```

Also, I wanted a trophy. The code above should run in O(n) time and minimize the amount of objects allocated. No guarantees on this being the 'best' approach. A benefit of the batching approach, and why the cost of `apply` (or spread invocation) is subsumed, is that there are significantly less calls to `String.fromCodePoint` and intermediate strings. YMMV - especially across environments.

Here is an [online benchmark](https://jsben.ch/KLACe). All tests have access to, and use, the same generated "A" array of 500k elements.

[image]

Comment: Nice one! Should that be let batch?

Comment: I think fromCodePoint also required based on OP

Comment: What is the runtime of this?  I rewrote with a pre-allocated array and was in the 20-30 milisecond range (as opposed to 19 *seconds* for other solutions that repetetively concatenated arrays).  I see the `apply` in the loop so I'm honestly skeptical. `apply` is really slow

Answer (score 2):

The given answers are of poor performance: i measured 19 seconds on one of them and the others are similar (*). It is necessary to **preallocate** the output array. The following is 20 to 40 **milli** seconds. Three orders of magnitude faster.

```
function wordArrayToByteArray(hash) {
    var result = [...Array(hash.sigBytes)].map(x => -1)
    let words = hash.words
        //map each word to an array of bytes
        .map(function (v) {
            // create an array of 4 bytes (less if sigBytes says we have run out)
            var bytes = [0, 0, 0, 0].slice(0, Math.min(4, hash.sigBytes))
                // grab that section of the 4 byte word
                .map(function (d, i) {
                    return (v >>> (8 * i)) % 256;
                })
                // flip that
                .reverse()
            ;
            // remove the bytes we've processed
            // from the bytes we need to process
            hash.sigBytes -= bytes.length;
            return bytes;
        })
    words.forEach((w,i) => {
        result.splice(i * 4, 4, ...w)
    })
    result = result.map(function (d) {
        return String.fromCharCode(d);
    }).join('')
    return result
}
```

(*) With the possible exception of @User2864740 - we are awaiting his numbers. But his solution also uses `apply()` inside the loop which leads to believe it will also be slow.

Comment: Numbers are only useful when compared relatively :)

Comment: Which is why I provided them.  The 19 seconds is one-for-one replacement with one of the other solutions. The key components of the slowdown are the repetitive application of `concat` and the usage of `apply`. Your solution avoids the first part but afaict not the second. I'd be interested to hear your numbers.

Comment: FWIW, this uses `fromCharCode`. That might have been an accidental change, as I did it too :( - Here are is an updated benchmark covering *just* the conversion process. https://jsben.ch/hutLb

Comment: Yours is probably of similar performance.  In any case it has the awarded.

Answer (score 0):

"Old fashion" JavaScript:

```
var N=125000;
var y="";
for(var i=0; i<N; i++)
  y+=String.fromCharCode(i);
console.log(y.length);
```

Worked with N=1000000

Comment: I expect this to have horrid performance characteristics without, perhaps, specific implementation optimizations. Conceptually this creates a new string each loop and copies over the original for O(n^2) bounds!! While it is possible that such can be optimized in a specific implementation, I would be hard pressed to suggest this approach in general. It may also not be correct for surrogate pairs.

Comment: “It’s not (just) you, it’s me.” - I’m also skeptical of the other answer.